# Modeling Business Operations: Linking Names to Code

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

So, I'm looking at putting my business operations (or rather, their names) in the database so that I can link them to user Roles (for authorization) and also setup a Notification system on operations.

The main spot of trouble is how to translate an operation (probably represented by a string, like "Customer.New" or "Customer.View") from the database into code that is run in the system. Most of the ways that I have come up with seem kludgy.

Example 1 - A general method to handle all operations

```
public static object RunOperation(string Op, string User, params object[] Parms)
{
    switch(Op)
    {
        case "Customer.View":
            return BLL.Facade.GetCustomerById((int)Parms[0]);
            break;
        case "Customer.New":
            return BLL.Facade.CreateCustomer(Parms[0] as Customer);
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

The thing I hate about this is all the casting. But authorization would be pretty easy. `Authorize(Op, User);`

Then there's this way:

```
[BusinessOp("Customer.New")]
public static int CreateCustomer(Customer NewCustomer)
{
    ...
}
```

But then authorization is a bit wonky, since I assume I'll have to pass the CreateCustomer method reference into the Authorize method (and different ops will have different method signatures). Then the Authorize method will have to use reflection to find the BusinessOpAttribute and get the string name of the operation (the way it's represented in the database).

I suppose another thing I could do is create a series of constants representing the string name of the operations and use them for the Authorize method, but just call the business method when it came time to execute the operation. But then I still do not have one item (be it a method or a string) representing the business operation to all parties.

Does anyone have experience with this, and is there maybe another option that I haven't considered?

**ANSWER**

Ultimately decided through comments with the accepted answer. I'll make a class for each business operation. Something like this:

```
[BusinessOperation]
public static class CustomerNew
{
    public const string Key = "Customer.New";

    public static bool Authorize(string UserName) // or perhaps IPrincipal User
    {
        // Authorize method will use key to check against database
        ...
    }

    public static int Invoke(Customer NewCustomer)
    {
        // Invoke method has well-defined parameters
        ...
        // Can also use key to notify listeners of operation completion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that we handle similar issues is to have the actual operation represent a concrete method on the specified class. The biggest issue with this is the params, which we always leave to the implementing method to deal with.

So in your case, I would refactor similar to:

```
var asValues = Op.Split('.');

switch(asValues[0].ToLower())
{

    case "customer":
        Type type = typeof(BLL.CustomerFacade);

        System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(asValues[1], System.Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);

        if (method != null)
        {
            return method.Invoke(BLL.CustomerFacade, Parms);
        }
        break;
```

Note that I changed the Facade to CustomerFacade and in this CustomerFacade, the GetCustomerById would change to View. This is just one way to approach this.

You could also keep everything in a single facade and change the method name to CustomerView, for example. Also, if there are other pieces of code dependent on the existing facade names, you could either change the operation name or add redirect methods that redirect the request to the correct underlying facade method.

This will probably need some tweaking according to your implementation, but it should give you the general idea.

The benefit to this approach is that you don't have to update this method every time you want to implement a new action.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is not the solution I would prefer, as the calling method still has to know internal details of the method it calls (knowing exactly which parameters to pass), violating the principle of encapsulation. However, if I can't find a better solution, I may end up doing something like this.

Comment: @KaseySpeakman: I agree, it's kind of a chicken and egg situation. However, you could invert control by examining the method's parameters and then asking the caller for the appropriate values. You could add a ValueFetch interface, for example, that would be implemented by the caller and would provide values for the parameters based on their names or using reflection (assuming an implementing class would have the values stored in properties). Then you just pass the implementing instance instead of the param array.

Comment: I'm thinking about making a class for each business op that has Authorize and Invoke methods, as well as a const Key that is the database's name for the operation. The Authorize method would use the key to authorize the operation, but the Invoke method would have well-defined parameters. It's extra work up front, but it does avoid reflection. Thoughts?

Comment: That sounds like a good approach. We actually use a very similar approach in our mobile app view/models.